# How can i rename a filename from vim?

Tags: vim, editor

```
vim .
```

Now I get the list of directory and files.

Now how can I rename a filename from that list of files?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be in like superuser? Anyway check NERDTree it helps a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In command mode:

`:E` opens up the directory view.
`R` renames the selected file. The shortcuts are listed above the listing.

If you use `vim .` you can rename with `R` (because it is the very same thing as above).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `qmv` (on debian-like systems `apt-get install renameutils`) which does exactly that *and* it honours your system default editor (VISUAL, EDITOR, execvp("editor"))

```
qmv *.cs
```

opens up an editor, you can %s///g what you like, use <kbd>C-a</kbd> / <kbd>C-x</kbd> to increment/decrement numbers - in short everything you ever wanted to. You can also rename in circular fashion, e.g.

```
      a.txt         b.txt
      b.txt         a.txt
```

or

```
      a.txt         b.txt
      b.txt         c.txt
      c.txt         a.txt
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the external `mv` command like this:

```
  :! mv oldfile newfile
```